# FabricJS - ZoomToPoint not working with backgroundImage

Tags: javascript, canvas, zooming, fabricjs

i use zoomtopoint and zoom to object. but not working with background. 
I want to zoom in on the object and the background. How can i ?

Example :
object size : 100x100 not zoom.
[image: object size : 100x100 not zoom.]
after zoom object size :100x100
[image: after zoom object size :100x100]

after zoom and The grid remained the same.

**zoom event**

```
document.addEventListener('wheel', function(event) {
        var evt = window.event || event;
        var delta = evt.detail? evt.detail*(-120) : evt.wheelDelta;
        var curZoom = canvas.getZoom();
        var newZoom = curZoom + delta / 4000;
        var x = event.offsetX;
        var y = event.offsetY;
        canvas.zoomToPoint({ x: x, y: y }, newZoom);
        if(event != null)event.preventDefault();
        return false;
        canvas.calcOffset();
    }, false);
```

**grid code:**

```
canvas.setBackgroundColor({source: src, repeat: 'repeat'}, canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas), function () {
        canvas.renderAll();
        proceed();
    });
```

**EDİT**

```
#canvas-background { display: inline-block; position: absolute; top: 0; right: 0; }
```

but i dont use css.

Background image

[image: Grid 50x50]

Thank you

Sorry, i cant speak english well.

Comment: If it is the canvas.style.background your are referring to then it is not part of the canvas 2D API and requires DOM/CSS transformations. Not something that fabricJS does. You need to add the background as an object to fabric so it can include it in the zoom

Comment: I think you're talking about adding a background image as an image object.

Comment: Yes. I do not know if fabric will let you set the image as repeatable but the 2D API lets you set a pattern via a bitmap. If fabric lets you create a pattern, create a pattern using the background bitmap. That way you can have it repeatable.

Comment: i try this code : `canvas.backgroundColor = new fabric.Pattern({source: image})` but not change :(

Comment: now i use setBackgroundImage(), but now, i cant repeat-x-y axis.

Comment: Sorry I can not help you any more as I know very little about fabric.

Comment: @forguta Can you post your background image and the CSS source, `src`?  I'll see which works better, repeating the "background" image when panning OR transforming the CSS when zooming.  Thanks and please.

Comment: look edit section :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Relevant code is below (and the rest is in the JSFiddle), note the canvas size and CSS container trick used to allow zooming out.

Example : object size : 100x100 not zoom.

[image: fabricjs canvas grid not zoom]

after zoom object size :100x100

[image: fabricjs canvas grid zoom]

after zoom and The grid is no longer the same.

```
fabric.Image.fromURL('data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAADIAAAAyCAIAAACRXR/mAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUAAAAJcEhZcwAADsMAAA7DAcdvqGQAAAASdEVYdFNvZnR3YXJlAEdyZWVuc2hvdF5VCAUAAADLSURBVFhH7ZnBCoMwEET9/68URBHSNj0UolFoI+aQickKlT05jz0MGQIPkb2kadu3ta42ff/MTtLRazct55bajOMjO0lHr920vnWMMTGV0GuphVALoRaiqNV1dq4TLsdUIrTe+z0fw+ndmEo0w/D61AmXYyqh1179WjGVuNLyl0eohVALuZ8Wtzwgt9zyiNxSC6EWQi1EUYtbHpBbbnlEbqmFUAuhFqKoxS0PyC23PCK31EKohVAL0dXK3vLSOX0TnKZ1z8fw/3uiW37L27QIZwrV4gAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==', function(img) {
  var patternSourceCanvas = new fabric.StaticCanvas();
  patternSourceCanvas.add(img);
  var pattern = new fabric.Pattern({
    source: function() {
      patternSourceCanvas.setDimensions({
        width: img.getWidth(),
        height: img.getHeight()
      });
      return patternSourceCanvas.getElement();
    },
    repeat: 'repeat'
  });
  var background = new fabric.Rect({
    width: canvas.getWidth(),
    height: canvas.getHeight(),
    fill: pattern,
    selectable: false
  });
  canvas.add(background, rectangle);
  canvas.renderAll();
});
```

Here's a working JSFiddle, https://jsfiddle.net/rekrah/86t2b8bs/.

Hope this helps.

**UPDATE:**

@forguta also wanted to ensure objects didn't go behind the background when `sendToBack()` was run. Made "repeated" background image into one image so `setBackgroundImage()` could be used (image size only increased to 64K and I'm sure could be compressed further).

[image: fabricjs canvas grid not zoom send to back]

Simpler code:

```
canvas.setBackgroundImage('data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAACcQAAAnECAIAAAChEWJqAAAACXBIWXMAAAsTAAALEwEAmpwYAAAAB3RJTUUH4QMDDwYflNda9wAAIABJREFUeNrs2TGO67qWhlHSotSFm7z5z+4NoQsoXJbFs8HObYoGbJxmslYk4JfgD053/u9///............', canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas), {
  // Needed to position backgroundImage at 0/0
  originX: 'left',
  originY: 'top'
});
```

Here's an updated working JSFiddle, https://jsfiddle.net/rekrah/u0srdsdr/.

Comment: Yeah, I tried that too. But I do not want the background to come in getObjects (). When I send the objects that I create to the back using sendtoBack (), the objects disappear. If you have an opinion about it, I can use it. Thanks again for your help, @TimHarker. :)

Comment: @forguta I updated my answer above.  I believe this is your easiest option.  There is another option I've been playing around with that makes use of CSS as a background image but it would take some work to have it scale and zoom insync. with the scaling and zooming (`canvas.zoomToPoint()`) of the canvas - but I believe it would be doable.